# Convert PHP Prepared Statements Within Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to convert the following php code into a prepared statements.

The code below querys for all games that has not started yet, delete all picks and then insert new picks.

```
$sql = "SELECT gameID, weekNum, gameTimeEastern FROM htb_schedule
            WHERE weekNum = " . $week . "
            AND (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) < gameTimeEastern
            AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) < '" . $cutoffDateTime . "') ";

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

        $sql = "DELETE FROM htb_picks WHERE userID = " . $user->userID . " AND gameID = " . $row['gameID'];
        $mysqli->query($sql);

        if (!empty($_POST['game' . $row['gameID']])) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO htb_picks (userID, gameID, pickID, weekN, timestamp) VALUES (" . $user->userID . ", " . $row['gameID'] . ", '" . $_POST['game' . $row['gameID']] . "', " . $week . ", NOW() )";
            $mysqli->query($sql);

        }
    }
}
```

The code below is my attempt at prepared statements.

```
$sql = "SELECT gameID, weekNum, gameTimeEastern FROM htb_schedule
            WHERE weekNum = ?
            AND (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) < gameTimeEastern
            AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) < '" . $cutoffDateTime . "') ";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $week);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($gameID, $weekNum, $gameTimeEastern);

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        $sql = "DELETE FROM htb_picks WHERE userID = ? AND gameID = ? ";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user->userID, $gameID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if (!empty($_POST['game' . $row['gameID']])) {

            $sql = " INSERT INTO htb_picks (userID, gameID, pickID, weekN, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW()) ";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("iisi", $user->userID, $gameID, $_POST['game' . $row['gameID']], $week);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

        }
    }
}
$stmt->free_result();
```

The code is suppose to DELETE and INSERT results but it's not doing that. What am I doing wrong?

If I use the following code below it will work but the first sql is not a prepared statment.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM htb_schedule
            WHERE weekNum = " . $week . "
            AND (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) < gameTimeEastern
            AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) < '" . $cutoffDateTime . "') ";

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

        $sql = "DELETE FROM htb_picks WHERE userID = ? AND gameID = ? ";

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user->userID, $row['gameID']);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

        if (!empty($_POST['game' . $row['gameID']])) {

            $sql = " INSERT INTO htb_picks (userID, gameID, pickID, weekN, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW()) ";

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bind_param("iisi", $user->userID, $row['gameID'], $_POST['game' . $row['gameID']], $week);

            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->close();

        }
    }
}
$query->free;
```

Comment: Any errors being outputted? Why not prepare `$cutoffDateTime` as well? Where is it failing, `select`, `delete`, or `insert`?

Comment: After implementing @RiggsFolly suggestion I get this error `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` its points to the `stmt2->bind_param("ii", $user->userID, $gameID);` after the DELETE sql

Answer (score 0):

You are over writing the `$stmt` that is controlling your while loop while you are inside the while loop. You even `->close()` it.

All you need to do is use a different variables name for the statement when you are inside the loop

Also you should check status of each mysqli command.

```
$sql = "SELECT gameID, weekNum, gameTimeEastern FROM htb_schedule
            WHERE weekNum = ?
            AND (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) < gameTimeEastern
            AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) < '" . $cutoffDateTime . "') ";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if ( ! $stmt ) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
$stmt->bind_param("i", $week);

if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
    echo $stmt->error;
}

$stmt->bind_result($gameID, $weekNum, $gameTimeEastern);

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        $sql = "DELETE FROM htb_picks WHERE userID = ? AND gameID = ? ";
        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        if ( ! $stmt2 ) {
            echo $mysqli->error;
        }
        $stmt2->bind_param("ii", $user->userID, $gameID);
        if ( ! $stmt2->execute() )
        {
            echo $stmt2->error;
            exit;
         }

        $stmt2->close();

        // stmt2 is closed and finished with, so its name can be reused

        if (!empty($_POST['game' . $row['gameID']])) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO htb_picks 
                            (userID, gameID, pickID, weekN, timestamp) 
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW()) ";
            $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
            if ( ! $stmt2 ) {
                echo $mysqli->error;
            }

            $stmt2->bind_param("iisi", $user->userID, 
                                       $gameID, 
                                       $_POST['game' . $row['gameID']], 
                                       $week);

            if ( ! $stmt2->execute() )
            {
                echo $stmt2->error;
                exit;
             }

            $stmt2->close();

        }
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Tried this. It's still not deleting and inserting results into the database.

Comment: I assume that `$user->userID` , `$gameID` and the `$_POST` values actually exist?

Comment: I added the error processing which might identify where the issue is, try this

Comment: Yes they exist. The code without the prepared statements works perfectly fine. I'm worndering once I bind result of  `$gameID` if that is available to use in the while loop?

Comment: Try the code with the error checking in it it will almost definitely identify where the issue is

Comment: I am getting no errors. I don't have errors turned off.

Comment: Did you add and run the code with all the mysqli error checking?

Comment: Yes I did. Can you check out my edit question. I added a semi solution that works at the end of the question. Its part prepared statement and part not. Maybe that'll help?